# can column name be number in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android aplication and used an external database with 70 rows and 100 columns. for each row, when My app user clicks on next button, the app goes to next column of database and shows it's content. So I must use numbers of 1 to 100 for my column's name to refer to selected column by increas or decreas it's number. but it occures error in eclipse. for example in ID = 1, when I select "mani" column, it works like a charm but shows nothing for "1" column.

```
Database Class :
package com.codegostarNiloo.negar;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String   DB_PATH;
public static String   DB_NAME = "negar.db";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context  myContext;



public Database(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
}



public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    copyDataBase();
    Log.d("isexist", "" + checkDataBase());
}



private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {}

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}



private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(DB_PATH);
    if ( !dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    File database = new File(dir, DB_NAME);
    if ( !database.exists()) {

        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
}



public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}



@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
}
```

MainActivity Class:

```
// database method :
    private void Database() throws Error {
    myDbHelper = new Database(MainActivity.this);
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }
}

// Select column 1 of row 1:
database();
db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from mohtava where ID = " + 1, null);
    if (c.moveToNext()) {
    String j=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("1"));
        } 
db.close();
c.close();
```

database : http://www.axgig.com/images/23013560911355303754.jpg

error :

```
05-02 02:36:18.187: E/CursorWindow(26741): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 3 columns.
05-02 02:36:18.188: D/AndroidRuntime(26741): Shutting down VM
05-02 02:36:18.188: W/dalvikvm(26741): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410e39a8)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.codegostarNiloo.negar/com.codegostarNiloo.negar.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:167)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at com.codegostarNiloo.negar.MainActivity.amoozesh(MainActivity.java:251)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at com.codegostarNiloo.negar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:114)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5125)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2289)
05-02 02:36:18.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26741):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: why don't you name your columns col1, col2, etc.?

Comment: I tested that and same error occurs !

Comment: Paste your error as text (formatted as code) rather than an image.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem has solved. I can read records from the columns that have numeric name!

I have used NOX emulator and my devise for test this application and they cached the database and refered to it, every times!

so, simply uninstalled NOX and removed previous installed app in my devise and then reinstalled...
All things works like a charm!